# What could go wrong as a consequence of terraforming a planet?

Tags: science-fiction, terraforming

For my money, human beings manage to do very few things, especially really big life-altering things, without there being "unintended consequences". What could be some of the unintended consequnces of trying to terraform a planet? I'm looking for 'natural' consequences, not social ones (got those covered), like environmental disasters or uncontrolled/new diseases.

The exact conditions of this process - how the terraforming is being done, what kind of planet it is being done on, etc. - is pretty flexible at this point, so if there are certain conditions that need to be met to create certain problems, that's alright. For example, I haven't decided if the planet has existing life on it or not (at a microorganism level), but if having it or not having it would help create problems, then I want to go with the thing that helps create the biggest problems, haha.

I'm especially interested in the disease/illness angle, and if that was a possible consequence, would love if it was more likely to impact some people but not others (kinda like how certain people are more vunerable to worse manifestations of Covid). It would also be helpful if the issues were somewhat unpredictable (obviously we're 'predicting' them right now, but story voodoo), or at least enough that the people terraforming wouldn't immediately know that their actions were causing the problem.

At this point, mostly want to know how likely "unintended consequences from terraforming" is and what kind of consequences those could theoretically be.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: "Spok could be reborn, and nobody wants that"< extract from the Romulan science directorates impact analysis of the Federations Genesis project, some liberties have been taken with the translation, it was longer, rather more emphatic and there were a lot more expletives in the original, but we think we've translated the general gist of it accurately.

Comment: Welcome onewordtest. This is *way* too broad and asking for a potentially infinite list of things. We work on a  1 question, 1 identifiable best answer basis (with the constraints in the question giving us what that would constitute). Could you edit to give us that?

Comment: VTC - I love the premise of the question - but a golden rule is that if an answer could be an entire book in-of-itself, then it's not appropriate for here. And IMO Terraforming, even just scoped to disease and illness **more** than meets that criteria. Case in point - I'm in NZ, we have very strict biosecurity laws due to native flora and fauna - a single species carrying unknown disease arriving could massively change the ecosystem. Terraforming is like that but on steroids.

Comment: One thing that needs narrowing down: Does the planet in question already harbor native life, or is it a lifeless ball (although not necessarily without an atmosphere or hydrosphere).

Answer (score 1):

1. Humans introduce [an invasive species](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invasive_species). Due to bad planning of ecosystems, humans release some lifeform which dominates the planet, kills the rest of the ecosystem, and ruins the planet.
2. Global warming/ cooling. Human plans to modify the temperature go wrong, and the planet gets excessively hot or cold.
3. Poisoning the world. Some attempt to modify the world releases lots of poisonous gas which kills everything on the planet not in a sealed suit.
4. Asteroid impact. An effort to bring in external material goes wrong, and an asteroid wrecks the surface of the planet, causing mass destruction and global cooling.
5. Mutated bug. One of the nanites or bacteria released to terraform the place mutates and does bad things, infecting and destroying all.

Answer (score 0):

The imported life (if that is included in you meaning of terraforming) such as trees, grass, fish, birds, animals, insects, etc. could get in the way of collecting resources.

The imported life could mutate in an extreme variety of ways that the terraforming management did not previously account for and create phenomenal toxicity in both chemical and biological conditions.

The terraforming could be far more expensive than estimated.

Maintaining the terraforming could not only be more expensive than estimated at first, but further become more expensive over time.

The terraforming could cause more problems than without it and be so difficult to control or remove that the area or planet would have to be abandoned.